# Cannot Import Name X

Tags: python, django

Currently trying to create a Models.py file for my Django project to be able to store questions in a database.

But every time i reference the model in my forms.py for the Meta Class I receive an import error.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Q1  

Question1_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'I Like Smoking'),
    ('2', 'I Dislike Smoking'),
    ('3', 'I Do not Smoke'),
    ('4', 'I Do not mind Smokers '),
)

class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
         required=False,
         widget=forms.RadioSelect,
         choices=Question1_CHOICES
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Q1
        fields = ['question']
        widgets = {
            'question': forms.RadioSelect()
        }
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .forms import Question1_CHOICES

class Q1(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question1_CHOICES)
```

My Error is as follows

> File "forms.py", line 3, in     from .models import Q1

Any help would be really appreciated as I'm stumped what it could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular import

forms.py is importing models.py

models.py is importing forms.py

I would recommend moving `Question1_CHOICES` into models.py. Follow the docs as an example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Models.py

```
from django.db import models  

Question1_CHOICES = ( ('1', 'I Like Smoking'), ('2', 'I Dislike Smoking'), ('3', 'I Do not Smoke'), ('4', 'I Do not mind Smokers '), )

class Q1(models.Model): 
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question1_CHOICES)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from .models import Q1, Question1_CHOICES  

class QuestionForm(forms.Form): 
    q1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField( required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=Question1_CHOICES ) 
    class Meta: 
        model = Q1 fields = ['question'] 
        widgets = { 'question': forms.RadioSelect() }
```